# Channel Entries - Is it possible to search title field with starts with?

Tags: channel-entries

Based on the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name), I can do "exact" and "contains" matching.

Is it possible to do a "starts with" search? For example, lets say I have this entries in the database

1. Web design
2. Web development
3. SEO and Web Marketing

when I search for `web`, I want to get the first and second entries but NOT the third.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search-parameter for the Channel Entries tag does not allow you to target a Title field. So either get creative with the Query module, or try one of these options:

#### 1. Low Search

[Low Search's Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search) *can* target entry titles *and* allows you to match by 'starts with'. That would look something like this:

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="services" search:title="web" starts_with="search:title"}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="services" search:title="^web"}
```

#### 2. Channel Query

[Channel Query](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-query) is like the Query module, but calls the native channel:entries module with its result. You should be able to use it like this (untested):

```
{exp:channel_query sql="SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE title LIKE 'web%' AND channel_id = 1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done.

The only way I can think about is to write addons to do this.

I think this plugin will be useful https://github.com/croxton/Search_fields

this plugin use the same way as EE but with some additional features.

u can hack it and add "starts with" feature.

Regard's.

Comment: I've used Search Fields before, and it works quite nicely.